# Can't recreate facebook user when deleted

Tags: passport.js, passport-facebook

1. I created a user using passport-facebook

   ```
   api.get('/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', {
       scope: 'email'
   }))
   ```
2. Deleted the user

   DELETE FROM users WHERE email = ?
3. goto #1 for recreating the user

But, when I tried #3 error occurs

```
Failed to deserialize user out of session
```

So I tried to delete the session on db

```
delete from sessions where session_id = 'p8TaEeb-GH87lbi-a5hpmY6YX6me6yHf'
```

And I tried #3 it works.

I put some logs to check passport-facebook works.

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
  clientID: config.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID,
  clientSecret: config.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET,
  callbackURL: '/api/auth/facebook/callback',
  profileFields: ['id', 'name', 'email', 'displayName', 'photos']
}, async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {

  //log for checking passport-facebook works
  console.log('Is it works??')

  const type = 'facebook'
  const nickname = profile.displayName
  const email = profile.emails[0].value
  const thumbnail = profile.photos[0].value
  try {
    let [existsUser] = await conn.query(`SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?`, [email])
    existsUser = existsUser[0]
    // is user already exists
    if (existsUser) return done(null, existsUser)

    const fields = { nickname, email, thumbnail, type }
    await conn.query(`INSERT INTO users SET ?`, fields)
    let [createdUser] = await conn.query(`SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?`, [email])
    createdUser = createdUser[0]

    return done(null, createdUser)
  } catch (err) {
    return done(err)
  }
 }))
})
```

But, log didn't appeared so seems to be FacebookStrategy not works when I do #3

Here's my passport.deserializeUser

```
passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
  const sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?'
  const fields = [id]
  try {
    const [user] = await conn.query(sql, fields)
    return done(null, user[0])
  } catch (err) {
    return done(err)
  }
})
```

Here's my session option

```
  const sessionOpt = {
    name: config.SESSION_COOKIE_KEY,
    secret: config.SESSION_SECRET_KEY,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: new MySQLStore(mysqlOpt),
    cookie: {
      maxAge: expiry,
      httpOnly: true
    },
    unset: 'destroy'
  }
```

Here's my full code

```
https://github.com/qkreltms/relay-novel-server/blob/develop/src/config/passport.js
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/6#issuecomment-4857287

I added if statement when user doesn't exists and `return done(null, false)`

```
passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
  const sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?'
  const fields = [id]
  try {
    const [user] = await conn.query(sql, fields)
    if (user.length === 0) return done(null, false)

    return done(null, user[0])
  } catch (err) {
    return done(err)
  }
})
```